# Stripe Checkout remember previous purchase

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a stripe checkout session which looks like this:

```
exports.createCheckoutSession = async (totalLicenses, currentURL, organizationID) => {
  try {
    const stripeCustomerID = await database.getStripeCustomerIDFromOrganizationID(organizationID);

    // If the customer does not exist return an error
    if (!stripeCustomerID) {
      throw new Error('Stripe customer does not exist.');
    }

    // https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      customer: stripeCustomerID,
      mode: 'subscription',
      line_items: [
        {

          price: 'price_2321srdspiOm5Cg52a',
          // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
          quantity: 60,
        },

      ],

      custom_text: {

        submit: {
          message: 'We will email you a documentation on how to register for classes',
        },
      },
      allow_promotion_codes: true,
      success_url: `${currentURL}/admin/licenses?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${currentURL}/cancel.html`,
    });

    return {
      url: session.url,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.trace(err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The price id is a graduated pricing:

[image]

All of this is working just fine, from the code above in the checkout screen it shows:

[image]

However, if I checkout the above and come back as the same customer and try to checkout 5 more. At this point I am expecting: $100 but it shows:

[image].

This behavior kind of makes sense to me but I would like to know how to make Stripe checkout understand that this customer has already purchases certain quantity so it should now move to a different pricing tier even though this is a new checkout.

Answer (score 0):

The tiering information won't be carried forward to a new checkout session. A workaround for your consideration: create a separate price that cost $20 each, before creating a checkout session, check how many products that the customer has already purchased (I assume you have your own DB to keep track of that). If the customer has purchased enough, use the $20 price for the checkout session creation.

You may also want to create $30, $40 and $50 prices for customers who purchased less products.

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking that this is my only option. I was just slightly concerned because I think with that approach we are creating a new monthly subscription every time the customer checks out new product. So they will be receiving multiple invoices. If it were one subscription everything they have purchased would show up in one bill each month.

Comment: You can just simply update the existing subscription with the additional items (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing). No need to create a new checkout session and therefore no new subscription is created. All you need to do is call the subscription update API from your backend code.